# Why standard MVC components like ViewBag, @Html.ActionLink and others are not recognized by VS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, compiler-errors, viewbag

Why standard MVC components like ViewBag, @Html.ActionLink

and others **are not recognized by VS** ?

[image]

What is the problem? I can't even compile standard MVC project

Comment: It happens to me when the cshtml is loading. If the problem persists, I either reopen the tab or restart VS. However, it stinks.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists you might have a nuget package that extends one of the front end components but has version incompatibility with a dll.

For example I had a BeginCollection nuget package that extended `Html` but referenced an old version of `System.Web.Mvc`. It meant it worked but intellisense would always state everything as an error after debugging the app once.